# What is Pythonic Sorcery?

Tags: sorcery-magic-kishuf

I saw "Pythonic Sorcery" mentioned on a list of things that would merit the death penalty in ancient Jerusalem. But, when I went to Google it, all I found are...more readings about the capital punishment in Judaism. So what is it? Where does this concept originate?

Comment: You may want to read about Ove and Yidoni

Comment: It's the power to raise the dead, apparently. https://books.google.com/books?id=vGUSDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA170&lpg=PA170&dq=Pythonic+Sorcery&source=bl&ots=w01nmRiw6G&sig=N1S-2VB_YWNW2r_zjcDxQKxwmDM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwitv5aLoZPaAhWOna0KHVnaDcAQ6AEIcDAJ#v=onepage&q=Pythonic%20Sorcery&f=false

Comment: Classical Jewish sources are not in English, so won't talk about "Pythonic Sorcery" as such. So I don't know how anyone's going to be able to answer this.

Answer (score 4):

"Pythonic sorcery" appears to be how [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_punishment_in_Judaism#Capital_sins_separated_by_the_four_types_of_capital_punishment) translates "Yid'oni" (ידעוני) (comp. the Hebrew in [Rambam's list](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_The_Sanhedrin_and_the_Penalties_within_their_Jurisdiction.15.10?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en)), although it's possible they were also referring to the Ba'al Ov, another form of necromancy. According to the essay brought by @ezra, pythonic sorcery is comprised of different forms of sorcery and divination done with relation to snakes. The Witch of Endor was called by classical and medieval Christians a "Pythonissa" which, according to [this entry](http://www.columbia.edu/dlc/garland/deweever/PQ/phitonis.htm), related her to the priestess of Apollo (better known as "the Oracle of Delphi"):

> "The priestess of Apollo was called Pythia. The witch of Endor is called *mulier Pythonem habens*, "a woman having the python," I Kings 28:7, indicating that she had some aspects of the pagan priestess. Isidore, in his discussion of magicians, says that the woman who called up Samuel was Pythonissa ([Etym VIII.ix.7, 21](http://www.intratext.com/IXT/LAT0706/_P6P.HTM)).
>
> The fiend explains to the summoner that sometimes devils arise with dead bodies and speak as reasonably and as fairly as Samuel did to the Phitonissa, FrT 1506-1511..."

This interpretation, which connects different forms of necromancy with snakes, isn't too far-off from the Talmud's explanation of the Yid'oni, which involved calling forth spirits through a bone of a mysterious animal called a "Yaddua" (see [here](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sanhedrin.65b.6?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi) and [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/121550/20472)).

My own guess is that this Greco-Roman term is the origin of the word "Pitom" which is used by our sages to describe such necromancers (see for example [Mishnah Sanhedrin 7:7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Sanhedrin.7.7?vhe=Mishnah,_ed._Romm,_Vilna_1913&lang=bi)). Compare especially the Latin "*Pythonem*", which has an "M" at the end. [And it seems](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sefer_HeArukh%2C_Letter_Alef.8?vhe=Sefer_HeArukh,_Lublin_1883&lang=bi) that the Aruch may have also thought so, or something similar.

It is known that the early Church Fathers ([Isidore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isidore_of_Seville) being the last of them) learned many Jewish traditions - not all of which survived in Jewish texts we have today - from local Jews, including Tannaim and Amoraim (see Jerome [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/119482/when-were-the-books-and-the-text-of-the-torah-settled/119491#119491) for example). It would not be far-fetched to say that Isidore's tradition of the Ba'alat Ov from the time of Shaul being some sort of pitom-serpent sorceress came from Jewish tradition. As for the connection to Apollo, let's not forget that the Plishtim, who most likely originated in the Grecian [Mycenaean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycenaean_Greece) culture, neighbored Yisrael for many centuries. It is possible that Israelite sorcerers received magical knowledge from them, thus resulting in the connection.

Comment: Fillet of a fenny snake,
In the cauldron boil and bake...